# PHP stop script from running again or delete variables or URL

Tags: php, paypal, return

Ok, not sure the best way to do this. i have done a serach through this website already but can't find the answer.....maybe as i don't know what i am looking for.

Basically I am using Paypal to auto return to a page, and in that page, a script runs that generates a serial number if the payment succeeded.

However, if the user was just to keep reloading the page, they will get infinite serial numbers sent to them, it just never ends.

How do I stop this from happening? The thing is once a URL has been created for the user, they can just copy and paste that link into any browser and it will keep sending new serial numbers.

What do I need to do?

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is my full code:

```
    <?php
    $pp_hostname = "www.sandbox.paypal.com"; 

    $req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';

    $tx_token = $_GET['tx'];
    $auth_token = "tokencode";
    $req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$pp_hostname/cgi-bin/webscr");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: $pp_hostname"));
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if(!$res){

    }else{

        $lines = explode("\n", $res);
        $keyarray = array();
        if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0) {
            for ($i=1; $i<count($lines);$i++){
            list($key,$val) = explode("=", $lines[$i]);
            $keyarray[urldecode($key)] = urldecode($val);
            }

        $firstname = $keyarray['first_name'];
        $lastname = $keyarray['last_name'];
        $itemname = $keyarray['item_name'];
        $amount = $keyarray['payment_gross'];

        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
        //$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $receiver_email = $keyarray['receiver_email'];
        $payer_email = $keyarray['payer_email'];
        //$businessemail = "contact@sample.com.au";

        echo ("<p><h3>Thank you for your purchase!</h3></p>");

        echo ("<b>Payment Details</b><br>\n");
        echo ("<li>Name: $firstname $lastname</li>\n");
        echo ("<li>Item: $itemname</li>\n");
        echo ("<li>Amount: $amount</li>\n");
        echo ("");

    echo "Thank you for your payment. Your transaction has been completed and a receipt for your purchase has been emailed to you.";
    echo $tx_token;



    $input = array("111", "222", "333");
    $filepath = ("Subscribe/" .  current($input) . ".txt");

    while (file_exists($filepath)) {
    $filepath = ("Subscribe/" . next($input) . ".txt");
    }

    $filepath = ("Subscribe/" . current($input) . ".txt");
    $SerialCurrent = current($input);
    $SerialEnd = end($input);

    $filepathlast = ("Subscribe/" . $SerialEnd . ".txt");

    if (file_exists($filepathlast)){//2nd If Start
        echo "No Serials Left";
    }
    else
    {
    $myfile = fopen($filepath, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $SerialCurrent);
    fclose($myfile);
    $filepath = ("Subscribe/" . reset($input) . ".txt");

        $gdate = date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Victoria');
        $DayIs = date("Y-m-d H:i e");

    mail($payer_email, "Subscription Details", "Thank you for subscribing. Please find your details below to register your software." . "\nSerial Number : " . $SerialCurrent . "\nProduct : " . $item_name . "\nDate : " . $DayIs);

    mail($receiver_email, "Subscription Details", "WindowCAD Subscribe" . "\nSerial Number : " . $SerialCurrent . "\nProduct : " . $item_name . "\nDate : " . $DayIs);
    }
       }
        else if (strcmp ($lines[0], "FAIL") == 0) {
          echo "Oh no - Error;";
        }
    }

    ?>


    Your transaction has been completed, and a receipt for your purchase has been emailed to you.<br> You may log into your account at <a href='https://www.paypal.com'>www.paypal.com</a> to view details of this transaction.<br>
```

Comment: In the url should definitely be something unique that you can store and use next times to detect duplicates.

Comment: It may be possible to use sessions to generate the serial only once. Can we see the code where you generate the serial ?

Answer (score 0):

Before regenerating and sending the (new) serial number, you do a check (db) if this customer has been sent a serial for that transaction already, if so, then do not generate/send, if not, send it, and record it in a DB that it was sent...

Without any specific examples we might not be able to help further.

Comment: O, thanks everyone. I have updated my origianl post with the code.